# Mongo DB Map Reduce when trying to process more than 100 records

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

I am new to Mongo DB , I am using Mongo DB 2.4.4 . When we are trying to pass more than 100 records in Mapreduce we are getting following error :

```
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost/XXXX" , "errmsg" : "exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'AAAA' of undefined\n    at _funcs2:1:296\n    at Array.forEach (native)\n    at _funcs2 (_funcs2:1:252) near 'ssionEvent.AAAA>0)
```

Following is the `MapReduceCommand` being used:

```
MapReduceCommand(eventsCollection,map,reduce,null,MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, compoundquery);
```

I have identical records but if Number of records are more than 100 its showing above error , if it is less than 100 then process successfully.
We are using following mongo options in our application.

```
"maxWaitTime=300"
"connectionsPerHost=100"
"threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier=1500" 
"socketKeepAlive=true"
"connectTimeout=60000"
"socketTimeout=60000"
"autoConnectRetry=true"
```

The Details about Map,reduce and compound query are as follows:

```
String map = "function() {"+
" if (this.Doc1 !== undefined & this.Doc1.innerDoc1 !== undefined) { "+
"emit({field1:this.Doc1.innerDoc1.field1,field2:this.Doc1.field2,field3:this.Doc1.field3,field4:this.Doc1.field4,field5:this.Doc1.field5},this);}";
String reduce = "function(keyMappedId, valuesPrices){"+
 "var amtValue1=0;"+ 
 "var processedObj=new Object();"+
 "valuesPrices.forEach(function(doc){"+
 if(doc.Doc1 !== undefined && doc.Doc1.AmtValue !== undefined && doc.Doc1.AmtValue>0){"+ 
     "var amtNumber=new Number(doc.Doc1.AmtValue);"+ 
     "amtValue1=amtNumber;}});"+
"if(amtValue1>0 && valuesPrices[0].Doc1 !== undefined){"+
        "valuesPrices[0].Doc1.AmtValue=amtValue1; }"+
"processedObj=valuesPrices[0];"+ 
"return {aggregatedObject:processedObj};}";



DBObject compoundquery =  QueryBuilder.start("_id").in(idList).get();
```

where idList will contain "_id" of the documents in the collection which i want to pass on to map reduce

```
MapReduceCommand cmd=null;
cmd = new MapReduceCommand("MyCollection",map,reduce,null,MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, compoundquery);
            MapReduceOutput out = eventsCollection.mapReduce(cmd);
```

Adding the Error output as below: 103 records

```
{ "aggregatedObject" : { "aggregatedObject" : { "_id" : "Order_REC16904427" , "Status" : "PROCESSING" , "Doc1" : { "field1" : "ABCS57829" , "field2" : "XYZ" , "AmtValue" : 9000.0 , "field3" : "AAAABCD" , "Doc2" : { "Serial_No" : "1" , "field4" : "Order" , "field5" : "ABC_1234"} , "Aggregation_Status" : "Submitted"}}}
```

For 311 Records

```
{ "aggregatedObject" : { "aggregatedObject" : { "aggregatedObject" : { "aggregatedObject" : { "_id" : "Order_REC16904427" , "Status" : "PROCESSING" , "Doc1" : { "field1" : "ABCS57829" , "field2" : "XYZ" , "AmtValue" : 9000.0 , "field3" : "AAAABCD" , "Doc2" : { "Serial_No" : "1" , "field4" : "Order" , "field5" : "ABC_1234"} , "Aggregation_Status" : "Submitted"}}}}}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the mapReduce method of MongoCollection?
   eventsCollection.mapReduce(map, reduce);

Comment: You have posted insufficient code; the `MapReduceCommand` is referencing some variables, it would be most helpful if you could show how these are implemented and what problem that map-reduce operation is trying to solve (sample documents in the collection and the expected output).

Comment: @yoooshi:    cmd = new MapReduceCommand(eventsCollection,map,reduce,null,MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, compoundquery);
         MapReduceOutput out = eventsCollection.mapReduce(cmd);

Comment: @chridam have added missing Info, JavaScript error I am able to resolve and able to process more than 100 documents , but as Map Reduce takes 100 records in a single chunk , If I try to process more than 100 records my resultant document is coming in a nested form like one added in question

Answer (score 0):

Basically, MongoDB supports no more than 100 levels of nesting for BSON documents.

([This discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/9jhHulYhT3Q) has same issue which you are facing. may be helpful I guess.)

Comment: This link might also helpful:
[**2.4.5 Map Reduce Concurrency**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/MongoDB-aggregation-guide-v3.0.pdf)
look for **2.4.5 Map Reduce Concurrency**
During the operation, map-reduce takes the following locks:
• The read phase takes a read lock. It yields every 100 documents